# Hash set that stores subclasses of certain class JAVA

Tags: java, generics, hashset

Consider the following situation:

```
public abstract class Vegetable {};

public class Tomato extends Vegetable {};
public class Cucumber extends Vegetable {};

public class Orange {};
```

The point is - I want my `HashSet` to store only something extending `Vegetable`, how do I do this? This should be simple..

..but `Set <? extends Vegetable> () hs = new HashSet <? extends Vegetable> ();` is not a working construction of course, Java wants me to specify what type of `Set` I want - `Tomato` or `Cucumber`, what if I just want anything vegetable?

I'd rather not to use any casts...

Comment: Just use `Set<Vegetable> set = new HashSet<Vegetable>()`

Comment: @tania why don't you just try `Set<Vegetable>`?

Comment: I know that you want to avoid casting, but using Tom's code and casting for Cucumber and Tomato is probably the best way to to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create

```
Set<SomeType> = new HashSet<SomeType>();
```

the set is capable of storing objects that belong to any subclass of `SomeType`. In your case, all you need is

```
Set<Vegetable> set = new HashSet<Vegetable>();
```

You can do this now:

```
set.add(new Tomato());
set.add(new Cucumber());
```

Doing this will trigger a compile error:

```
set.add(new Orange()); // Does not compile
```

As far as casts go, you wouldn't need to cast objects on their way into the `set`. However, if you need a specific type (i.e. not simply `Vegetable`) on retrieval, you would need a cast.